# C# Program gets stuck in FtpWebResponse after server disconnects

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

I have a C# program that checks a ftp directory for new files every x seconds. If a new file is found it is downloaded. That works fine. If I start the program without running the ftp server the program loops and returns a message that the server cannot be reached. Then I start the server and the program connects as it should. But if I quit the ftp server again my program gets stuck in the FtpWebResponse.

I have a using statement block in a try catch block to close all connections.

```
while (true)
{
    //...
    FtpFileList = null;
    while (FtpFileList == null)
    {
        FtpFileList = await GetFtpFileList(adress, user, password);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
    await Task.Delay(27000);
    //...
}


public static async Task<List<string>> GetFtpFileList(string address, string user, string password)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync()) //The program gets stuck here
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                returnValue.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        AddToLogFile(DateTime.Now + ": " + "FTP directory updated");
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        AddToLogFile(DateTime.Now + ": " + e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I expect the program to reconnect to the server after the connection was lost but instead it gets stuck.

Any help and hints how to solve that issue is appreciated.

Comment: I had trouble using HttpClient async methods when it receives exceptions.  Try adding .ConfigureAwait(false) ...    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))

Comment: @TheMikeInNYC Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that did not solve the problem. It stills runs into the FtpWebResponse and won't move on after disconnecting the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to let you know I solved the issue by implementing a workaround: Instead of using `await request.GetResponseAsync()` I use the normal GetResponse() method in another thread which works without any problems so far: `await Task.Run(() => request.GetResponse())`

Answer (score 0):

Use `FtpWebRequest.GetResponse` instead of `FtpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync` ( as `GetResponseAsync` is not overridden in `FtpWebRequest` and comes from the base `WebRequest` class, where it seems to it can't handle some specific FTP use cases)

If you need to await something just replace this:

```
FtpWebRequest request = ...
var response = (FtpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();
return response;
```

with that:

```
var response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
return await Task.FromResult(response);
```

Comment: `WebRequest.GetResponseAsync` only calls `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse`, which are implemented in `FtpWebRequest`, so the *"where it seems to it can't handle some specific FTP use cases"* is not well-founded (I do not question the fact there there *may be* a bug, but not the way your answer suggests).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, I thought so. But for some FTP servers the calls `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse` of the base `WebRequest` class seem to be not enough. Sync version `FtpWebRequest.GetResponse` works well for them. So it seems something needs to be revisited in async version of `FtpWebRequest` code of the begin/end implementations...